# C# How to convert Poco to List<Poco> without knowing which poco you're using

Tags: c#, reflection, poco

I've got a method that accepts ***any*** POCO. The method then needs to be able to check to see if the POCO is a `List<Poco>`. If it's not a list, it needs to convert it to a list.

Example

```
MyCustomMethod(object input)
{
    // if !input is list
    // convert input to list
}
```

And I would call it as such

```
MyCustomMethod(Pocos.foo);
MyCustomMethod(Pocos.bar);
```

Remember `MyCustomMethod` has no idea what poco is being sent to it. All it knows is to check if the object is a list, and if it's not, it needs to convert it to a list of that same object.

What would be the easiest way to approach this?

EDIT:

Some reasoning for this might help. I'm building a [sencha-touch](/questions/tagged/sencha-touch) app, and the `Ext.Data.Store` requires all JSON data to be in an array.

I'm building my WebService using [asp.net-mvc-3](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3) and I've got a custom `JsonPResult`. The JsonPResult accepts any object and returns that object as JsonP. If I'm sending a list to the JsonPResult, everything is gravy. If I'm just sending a single object, Sencha Touch pukes until I put that object into an array.

In order to keep things DRY, I'd like the JsonPResult to check if any object is a list, and do the work, rather than repeating myself in every controller.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this method? Why not, for example, make the parameter to your method a List<T>, and thus require that callers *pass in a list*.

Comment: @dlev - hopefully my edit above will help clarify.

Comment: RE: Your edit. DRY is all well and good, but your code will be a lot cleaner if you just package your single objects into single-item lists prior to sending, rather than bothering with the nonsense you'll need otherwise (even though that nonsense is only in one place.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do a safe cast:

```
var list = obj as List<Poco>;
if (list != null)
   // It's a list and you now have a reference
else
    list = new List<Poco> { (Poco)obj };
```

**Edit** to support any POCO, you'll need to use generics, so here is a generic extension method for you:

```
public static IList<T> AsList<T>(this T item)
{
    var list = item as List<T>;
    if (list != null)
        return list;

    return new List<T>() { item };
}
```

And some examples:

```
string name = "Matt";
var list = name.AsList();

List<string> names= new List<string>() { "Matt" };
var list2 = names.AsList();
```

Both `list` and `list2` will be lists of strings, but in the second instance, it has returned the casted list directly, instead of creating a new one and inserting itself into it. Type inference takes care of the generic argument, and it can be applied to any type.

Comment: I've clarified my question a bit. I'm not sure if this approach will work since I have no idea which poco I'm using.

Comment: Deleted mine, rereading @rockin's question obviously supports @Matthew's answer.